# content overlapping sidebar

Tags: html, css, positioning, containers

I have content that is overlapping the sidebar. If you look at the margin and padding for the sidebar container, you'll see that I had to I've tried numerous things including adjusting the position, but nothing works-

***EXAMPLE SCREENSHOT:
http://tinyurl.com/cefamyt

***WORKING EXAMPLE
http://www.bestthrillermovielist.com/indextest.php#topofpage

***ALSO
when I set the sidebar container to a set height, say, 4000px; instead of the way I currently have it, none of the movie content overlaps into the sidebar. I've tried to get the sidebar container to stretch the full height of the window to no avail***

The content from #movieinfo is overlapping the content from the sidebar ONCE the sidebar content ends. The margin/padding on the #sidebarcontainer allow the sidebar to extend to the complete length of the screen, but for some reason, the #movieinfo content slides to the right underneath where the sidebar content ends.

CSS:

```
#container {
    max-width:90%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#movieinfo {
    padding-right:375px;
    margin-top:25px; 
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
}

#sidebarcontainer {
    float: right; 
    width:345px;
    background:#fff;
    margin-bottom: -5000px; 
    padding-bottom: 5000px; 
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#movieright {
    float:right; 
    width:340px;
    height:100%; 


    }

#movierightcontainer {
    float:right;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    margin-top:0px;
    height:100%;
    padding: 0 2%;

}

.movienav {
    width: 320px;
    height: 430px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display:inline;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-bottom:45px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="movieinfo"> 
        <?php include("sidebar.php");?>
 <div class="movienav"></div>
    </div>
</div>

***SIDEBAR.php***
<div id="sidebarcontainer">
    <div id="movierightcontainer">
        <div id="movieright"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Replicate the problem in jsFiddle.

Comment: Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gu5FM/), still not sure what the problem is though.  OP should be more specific than "content is overlapping" unless they have specific visuals to show.

Comment: The elements are not overlapping, i think they're just contained one inside of another. If you don't want them to be that way you must put them one after another. And put for an example float right if you want them to the right. Maybe smth like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gu5FM/
Am I close to what you want?

Comment: I was able to upload a pic- please see link above

Comment: If your design is responsive consider building on something like twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are putting everything in `#container` There needs to be a separate div for the left column than the right column.  The movie posters are overlapping the right column because the right column is floated right and there isn't anymore content.  Which is why adding height to the right column worked.

I've created a simplified version of what needs to happen in a jsfiddle.  I made the posters smaller, so it is easier to view in their preview window.  But the concept is correct.

[Here is the jsfiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/AXkTM/)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to up-vote yet, but I will come back to this once I do. Thanks again!

Comment: Just noticed that #movieinfo is set to 75% width- I tried this before on 2 screen widths: 1600 and 1920. The 1600 filled in nicely, the 1920 ran out of room for the fourth movie in each row and there was then a large gap between the end of the last movie on each row and the sidebar. I will see how this goes.

Comment: then you might consider percentages for the div's that surround the movie.  That way there will always be 'x' number across